# ffmpeg: Create a black background video from audio, for Youtube upload

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

I have MP3 audio that I would like to turn into video, by joining the audio with a solid black background. I then want to upload the video to Youtube.

Using ffmpeg, I have tried this command, and a few adjacent variants:

`ffmpeg -i 'black.png' -i 'input.mp3' -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a copy 'output.mp4'`

*(where `black.png` is a PNG file that is 640×480 pixels).*

However, when uploading the video `output.mp4` to Youtube via Creator's Studio, I get the error:

> Processing abandoned. The video could not be processed.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Youtube requires a video *stream* but your image is a single frame. Loop it to create a stream and terminate output when audio ends by adding -shortest.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i black.png -i 'input.mp3' -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -shortest 'output.mp4'
```

I don't remember if YT accepts MP3 in MP4. If it does, you can keep `-c:a copy`. `-pix_fmt yuv420p` is usually required, but YT will re-encode anyway to that pixel format.

Comment: With `-pix_fmt yuv420p` per the answer below, the resulting video plays on macOS too.

Answer (score 26):

Alternatively you can have `ffmpeg` generate the black video with the [color source filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) instead of making an image:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x720:r=5 -i audio.mp3 -crf 0 -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

- Since it is just black video this is one case with lossless mode (`-crf 0`) will have a smaller file size than the default lossy mode.
- The resulting file may not play in your player or device, but it will on YouTube.

Comment: What's the `-f lavfi` there for?

Answer (score 2):

Probably becaue pixel format is wrong, add to command: -pix_fmt yuv420p

Comment: I will add that to the command, thanks. But unfortunately it didn't help with the upload issue.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same result, on macOS, I'm using:

`ffmpeg -hwaccel videotoolbox -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x720:r=25/1 -i input_audio.mp3 -c:v h264_videotoolbox -q:v 50 -c:a aac -shortest output.mp4`